# Best way to watch for files

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

OK I have an application that produces some contracts based on a file that is created by another app.

I have implemented a filewatcher to watch for the file being created and it then kicks off a `backgroundworker` process to create the contracts based on the filename.

The problem I am having is that during the background worker process I set `EnableRaisingEvents` to false so that the app does not start to process a different set of contracts whilst the first is running (It's also to stop calling the background worker whilst it is running as it cant run 2 things at once!).

All works fine, the other app creates a file, filewatcher picks it up and starts processing, the problem is that when processing is finished the filewatcher is re-enabled but I assume it wont pick up any files that were created when `EnableRaisingEvents` was false - and so if the application that creates the initial file to produce the contracts happens to create another file whilst my app is processing it will just be left.  Does that make sense? And what is the best way round this?

I had thought of having another process that when the initial contract creation is finished would then look in the directory for other files created between the time when the filewatcher was disabled and if there were none it would then re-enable the filewatcher but I am wondering if there is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: you could queue changed files into a List<T> or better Queue<T> and then process queue sequentially

Answer (score 0):

You could split your process in tasks. One task is the FileRegistrator , which picks up new files, registers them in database. It runs all the time, no need to EnableRaisingEvents to false.

The next task is the ProcessorTask (or whatever name) which will query the database, find the first one and processes it. It will query the database at regular times to see if a new file is registered.

You could implement this little processor using Quartz.NET scheduler in a windows service.

(I did about the same a while ago, but I didn't use FileSystemWatcher)

Answer (score 0):

A BlockingCollection would do this.
Keep FileWatcher hot and let it add to the blocking collection.
The consumer just processes the collection one at a time.

[BlockingCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

```
class AddTakeDemo
{
    // Demonstrates: 
    //      BlockingCollection<T>.Add() 
    //      BlockingCollection<T>.Take() 
    //      BlockingCollection<T>.CompleteAdding() 
    public static void BC_AddTakeCompleteAdding()
    {
        // here you need to synch as it would have missed any 
        // new files while the application was down 
        // yes L-Three and any files that were not yet processed 
        // clearly the existing program is an end to end synch 
        // or no synch at all as it could be nothing else 
        using (BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>())
        {

            // Spin up a Task to populate the BlockingCollection  
            using (Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //  FielSystem watcher                    
                bc.Add(fille);

            }))
            {

                // Spin up a Task to consume the BlockingCollection 
                using (Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Consume consume the BlockingCollection 
                        while (true) Console.WriteLine(bc.Take());
                        // process the file
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException)
                    {
                        // An InvalidOperationException means that Take() was called on a completed collection
                        Console.WriteLine("That's All!");
                    }
                }))

                    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @L-Three I see no requirement for persistence in the question.

Comment: No, it was just a question because I didn't know this one.

Comment: @L-Three No it is not persistent but if the app went down it would need to do fresh synch on the file systems anyway as the filesystemwatcher would not have caught file systems events that happened while the app was down.

Comment: Small remark: what if there were many file changes, and there was a queue of tasks waiting to be executed by your process; and the system crashes. In that case you would loose tasks and as such the system would not be reliable.

Comment: There should only be a maximum of say 5 or 6 files so thats not a problem

Comment: Sounds like this is the way to go but Im not sure how to implement it, will have a dig around!

Comment: @L-Three Asked and answered.  What part of synch on start is not clear?  Even with a persisted queue while app was down items would not have gone in the queue.  So, your persisted answer ignores any FileSystemEvents that happened while the app was down then yes YOUR system is not reliable.

Comment: You missed the point. I wanted to know if it was important to make a reliable system, in case of a crash or something else that happened. In that case you would also not use FileSystemWather. If this is not the case, BlockingCollection is fine.

Comment: @L-Three You still miss the point.  I know what persisted means.  A queue can only persists what goes in the queue.  From your solution "One task is the FileRegistrator, which picks up new files, registers them in database. It runs all the time."   Your assumption that FileRegistrator runs all the time makes your solution unreliable.

Comment: Not true. If it restarts, it continues from where it left off. You're mixing concepts, I'm afraid.

Comment: @user1779064 See that link.  It is just the AddTakeDemo.  T1 is the FileSytemsWatcher but you don't bc.CompleteAdding();

Comment: @L-Three Exactly IT continues where it left off.  When FileRegistrator continues where it left off it missed any files that were added while it was down.  You assumption that FileRegistrator runs all the time makes that solution unreliable.  So what if ProcessorTask continues where it left off - it can only process what went in the queue.

Comment: No, I don't use FileSystemWatcher as I already said before; I poll the file system myself (as FileSystemWatcher could be unreliable on its own) and so I don't miss any file. But this is getting out of scope for this question.

Comment: @L-Three Your assertion the use of a non-persisted file queue makes a solution unreliable makes the assumption the start up synch is not and end to end synch.  Based on the stated question there if NOT a start up problem - clearly he has logic to deal with start up.  This is direct and reliable answer to the stated question.

Comment: I never said it was not, what are you talking about!

Comment: @L-Three What part of end to end is not clear?  Yes you did infer it was not end to end.  "Tasks waiting to be processed would be lost."  A unprocessed task would not have produced output so a start up end to end comparison (synch) of input to output would identify that input as not processed.